# Scatter plot with specifc conditions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Suppose that I have this data set

```
x1 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.7])
x2 = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.4,0.6])
c  = np.array([  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

I want a scatter plot of `x1,x2` under the following condition: if the corresponding index for `(x1[i],x2[i])`
in `c` is `c[i]==1` then plot this a marker as a red X , but if the corresponding index for `(x1[i], x2[i])` in `c` is `c[i]==0` then plot the marker at `(x1[i], x2[i])` as a blue O.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using numpy, it is rather easy to get elements (or indices) where certain rule (comparison) is satisfied.

You can get an array of boolean values which corresponds to some condition acted on elements of existing array:

```py
print(c==0)
[False False False False False  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Also, you can access only some elements of array using the array of booleans (same as the size of initial array):

```py
print(x1[c==1])
[0.1 0.3 0.1 0.6 0.4]
```

or more complex operations and/or set values:

```py
x1[x2 < 0.5] = 0
print(x1)
x2[x2 < 0.5] = 10
print(x2)
```

```
[0.  0.  0.1 0.6 0.  0.  0.5 0.  0.  0.7]
[10.  10.   0.5  0.9 10.  10.   0.6 10.  10.   0.6]
```

For even more complicated conditions, there are [logical functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.logic.html) for NumPy arrays.

**This approach (NumPy) is significantly faster than using loops and you should utilize it whenever it is possible!**

Applying above, it is easy to solve your problem:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.7])
x2 = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.4,0.6])
c=np.array([ 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 ])

plt.plot(x1[c==0], x2[c==0], 'bo')
plt.plot(x1[c==1], x2[c==1], 'rx')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is efficient way or not but you can do this,

```py
i = 0
for (p1,p2) in zip(x1,x2):
    if(c[i]==1): 
        plt.scatter(p1, p2, marker='x', color='red')
    else: 
        plt.scatter(p1, p2, marker='o', color='blue')
    i+=1
```

check other marker shapes here,

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html

Comment: This is not really a good solution. It can be **extremely slow** even for moderate number of points. U can use `scatter`, but logical conditions should be done using numpy's built-in conditioning/indexing whenever is possible.

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing out. I saw your solution, it is great.