# Scatter plot with 4 conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I've used the answer of another question ([Scatter plot with specifc conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697936/scatter-plot-with-specifc-conditions)), written below, to create a scatter plot under two conditions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.7])
x2 = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.4,0.6])
c=np.array([ 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 ])

plt.plot(x1[c==0], x2[c==0], 'bo')
plt.plot(x1[c==1], x2[c==1], 'rx')
```

But i need to create a plot using 4 different conditions. Using a dataframe called `data` i've taken the columns referred to the x-axis and the y-axis (x, y in the code below), and the two lists of conditions.

```
x = data["validation_WES"]
y = data["CalcESR_R3_refitted"]
t = data["target"]
p = data["prediction"]
```

For each sample (which have specific values of "validation_WES" and "CalcESR_R3_refitted") these are the conditions:

- if t==1 and p==1 ---> green circle
- if t==1 and p==0 ---> green x mark
- if t==0 and p==1 ---> red x mark
- if t==0 and p==0 ---> red circle

How can I plot a scatter plot with these conditions? The code below is too slow and does not work:

```
c = []
for i in t:
    for j in p:
        if t[i]==1 and p[j]==1:
            c.append(4)
        if t[i]==1 and p[j]==0:
            c.append(3)
        if t[i]==0 and p[j]==1:
            c.append(2)
        if t[i]==0 and p[j]==0:
            c.append(1)

plt.plot(x[c==4], y[c==4], 'go')
plt.plot(x[c==3], y[c==3], 'gx')
plt.plot(x[c==2], y[c==2], 'rx')
plt.plot(x[c==1], y[c==1], 'ro')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution that doesn't use the for loop, but for now this code works:

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    merged_list = [(p1, p2) for idx1, p1 in enumerate(list1) 
    for idx2, p2 in enumerate(list2) if idx1 == idx2]
    return merged_list
      

tp = merge(t,p)
c = []
for i in tp:
    if i==(1,1):
        c.append(4)
    elif i==(1,0):
        c.append(3)
    elif i==(0,1):
        c.append(2)
    elif i==(0,0):
        c.append(1)

c_array = np.asarray(c)

plt.scatter(x[c_array==4], y[c_array==4], c='g', marker='o')
plt.scatter(x[c_array==3], y[c_array==3], c='g', marker='x')
plt.scatter(x[c_array==2], y[c_array==2], c='r', marker='x')
plt.scatter(x[c_array==1], y[c_array==1], c='r', marker='o')
```